# PHP, MySQL: BETWEEN operator not working with values with different amount of numbers

Tags: php, sql, between

My SQL task $query in PHP isn't working with values that has different amount of numbers (example. XXX and XXXX => 700 and 1100,800 and 1200 and 900 and 1300:

```
//Applying values from <form>:
$pirmas = $_POST['ieskoti'] - 200;
$antras = $_POST['ieskoti'] + 200;

// So when $_POST['ieskoti'] is 800, 900, 1000 and 1100, this task is not working:
$query = 'SELECT * FROM prekes WHERE prek_kaina BETWEEN "'. $pirmas .'" AND "'. $antras .'";';
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

With other values it works perfectly, because BETWEEN operator works with values with same amount of numbers: 500 and 900, 1000 and 1400 and etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `not working` mean, exactly? Are you not getting the expected result? What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: think you mean `digits` instead of `numbers` in your post, now the answer of aioros makes sense imho ;) it's a string comparison not comparing numbers (as you intend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the quotes around your numbers, so they are not interpreted as strings:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM prekes WHERE prek_kaina BETWEEN '. $pirmas .' AND '. $antras .';';
```

Answer (score 4):

You're enclosing your range values in quotes, so MySQl is doing a string comparison. Remove the quotes for numeric values. Try this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM prekes WHERE prek_kaina BETWEEN '. $pirmas .' AND '. $antras .';';
//                                Double quotes removed ^            ^    ^            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try this,
//Applying values from <form>:
$pirmas = $_POST['ieskoti'] - 200;
$antras = $_POST['ieskoti'] + 200;

// So when $_POST['ieskoti'] is 800, 900, 1000 and 1100, this task is not working:
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `prekes` 
          WHERE prek_kaina BETWEEN "'. $pirmas .'" AND "'. $antras .'"';
$result = mysql_query($query);
```